# Casting Function Arguments in LLVM

Tags: c, llvm

I have LLVM IR that looks like

```
%7 = load i32** %ok, align 8
call void @free(i8* %7) #3
```

I want to extract `%7` from the argument list of `free` and check if the previous `Instruction` (%7) and the argument instruction are same. The part of my code for this purpose looks like

```
if(CallInst* call_inst = dyn_cast<CallInst>(&I)) {   // I is the Instruction
   Function* fn = call_inst->getCalledFunction();
   StringRef fn_name = fn->getName();
   if (fn_name == "free") {    // fn_name is the called function name
       for(auto args = fn->arg_begin(); args != fn->arg_end(); ++args) {
           Instruction* arg = dyn_cast<Instruction>(&(*args));
           if (arg != NULL)
               errs() << arg->getOperand(0)->getName() << "\n";  // to check
           if (arg == parent_free_bitcast_inst) {
               // do something
        }
    }
```

The code does not work. I have tried casting but still `arg->getOperand(0)->getName()` results in an error instead of `ok`. Can anyone guide me on how can I go about doing this?

Comment: You haven't shown what `fn` is, but I'm guessing it's the `Function` and not the `CallInst`. If so you're iterating over the parameters in the function definition or declaration, not the arguments to the call.

Comment: Thanks. Can you guide me on how can I iterate over the arguments to the call?

Comment: @IsmailBadawi Thanks a lot. I get it that I should be using ``CallInst`` instead of ``Function``. Can you write it as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't shown what `fn` is, but I'm guessing it's the `Function` and not the `CallInst`. If so, you're iterating over the parameters in the function definition or declaration, not the arguments to the call. You can just use the `CallInst` instead of `fn` and the same code should work.